# How to find input date pattern is dash or slash or space in rubymine or ruby

Tags: regex, ruby, rubymine

when input date as `mm-dd-yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` or `mm dd yyyy`, based on the pattern i need to format my own. How to find the input date is of which pattern? in ruby/rubymine/watir. Below is the rubymine cucumber code

```
Then(/^I see correct (.*) on the form$/) do |mdate|
  mdate1 = Date.strptime(mdate,"%m-%d-%Y").strftime("%a %b %d %Y 00:00:00 GMT+0000")
  puts "parsing output1 is #{mdate1}"
```

Here `mdate` can be any pattern as described above, currently `strptime` will work for only one pattern. If it need to work for other pattern how to proceed?

Comment: use regex pattern!

Comment: Is it one of those 3 formats or can there be more / others?

Comment: BTW, what exactly do you have to determine the pattern? A formatted date string or maybe an `<input type="date">` tag or an input with `pattern` attribute?

Comment: @Stefan only those patterns. when i receive any of those patterns in a variable, I use that variable to format using strptime(date, ""%m-%d-%Y") or strptime(date, ""%m/%d/%Y") or strptime(date, ""%m %d %Y"). Then again i format using strftime to get the desired output

Comment: @Ganesh sounds as if you already found a solution. Maybe you could show your current code and explain the problems you have with it. (along with examples)

Comment: added the code above but not formatted

Comment: So [format it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow/51145#:~:text=6%20Answers&text=If%20you%20post%20code%20or,format%20and%20syntax%20highlight%20it.&text=Or%20for%20block%20code%2C%20you,%22it%20works!%22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regular Expression Matching and Case Statements

If your question is simply about how to match the data you described with a regular expression in Ruby, you can use a pattern like:

```
input_date =~ %r"\b\d{1,2}([-/ ])\d{1,2}\1\d{4}\b"
```

However, the validity of the match will depend on the quality of your data set. There are lots of ways that it could fail to match, or match non-date data. You have to know your data well to craft a useful-but-minimalist regular expression that matches only what you want.

On the other hand, if your question is about *which* pattern has matched, then:

```
input_date =~ %r"\b\d{1,2}([-/ ])\d{1,2}\1\d{4}\b"

# print the format based on delimiter used
case input_date.scan(%r"[-/ ]").first
when "/" then p "mm/dd/yyyy"
when "-" then p "mm-dd-yyyy"
when " " then p "mm dd yyyy"
end
```

You can adjust the action to suit your needs, such as defining a pattern for [Date#strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime), [DateTime#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime), setting a variable, or invoking one or more methods to craft or format your date object. This should definitely get you pointed in the right direction, though.

Comment: Thanks for your information. how to make if Input year with 2 or 4 digits in the regex. Currently if I give 6-5-20, its printing as 6-5-0020. Pls let me know

Comment: @Ganesh You'd need something like `%r"\b\d{1,2}([-/ ])\d{1,2}\1(\d{2}|\d{4})\b"` to capture either a two- or four-digit year. Don't use `\d{1,4}` because that would also match things like `6-5-202` which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

By matching the string with the following regular expression the divider character will be saved to capture group 1.

```
/(?<!\d)\d{2}([- \/])\d{2}\1\d{4}(?!=\d)/
```

[Start your engine!](https://rubular.com/r/PasJwPTr6bsdVc)

Since you will attempt to convert the matched string to a `Date` object, you will find at that time if it is a valid date. There is therefore no need for the regex to limit the possibilities for months to 01-12 or days to 01-31; `\d{2}` is sufficient.

Ruby's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<!\d)   : use a negative lookbehind to assert the previous character
            is not a digit
\d{2}     : match 2 digits
([- \/])  : match a character in the character class and save to
            capture group 1
\d{2}     : match 2 digits
\1        : match the content of capture group 1
\d{4}     : match 4 digits
(?!=\d)   : use a negative lookahead to assert the next character
          : is not a digit
```